# Python Selenium Not getting .text Attribute from table

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am having issues scraping the **.text** attribute from the  tag.  I am trying to get the quantities in the Quantity column.  There are 7 of them as shown below

[image: Text]

I am attaching my code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC, wait
import time


driver = webdriver.Firefox()


driver.get('https://www.unisourceprint.com/standard-business-cards/')



WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//table/tbody/tr/td[2]')))
quantities = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//table/tbody/tr/td[2]')

for i in quantities:
    print(i.text)

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue** in your code was that you were trying to fetch the text without clicking on <kbd>Pricing</kbd> element.

**Check the fixed code below:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC, wait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.unisourceprint.com/standard-business-cards/')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='Pricing']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//table/tbody/tr/td[2]')))
quantities = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//table/tbody/tr/td[2]')

for i in quantities:
    print(i.text)

driver.close()
```

**Console Result:**

```
250
500
1000
2500
5000
10000

Process finished with exit code 0
```